# Editing an element's style based on the "value" attribute of its child element

Tags: jquery, css, attributes, parent-child, background-color

I have `input` elements nested inside `label` elements like so:

```
<label class="color-button">
    <input type="color" value="#012345">
</label>
<label class="color-button">
    <input type="color" value="#6789AB">
</label>
<label class="color-button">
    <input type="color" value="#CDEF01">
</label>
...
```

Now I want to give each `label` the `background-color` specified by its child's `value`. I came up with this jQuery code:

```
$(".color-button").css("background-color", this.children().attr("value"));
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your example, `this` doesn't refer to each element in your jQuery object. You can either loop through the object or, since [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) handles looping for you, pass a callback function as the second parameter. The context of this function will be each element in the object.
- jQuery has [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value property of form elements.

```
$(".color-button").css("background-color", function(){
    return $(this).find('input').val();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqLo24pu/)